# Haskel parse error on input ')' in a fuction

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

Basically i have this code

```
ola xs = foldl (\acc x -> if (chr x >= 65 && chr x <= 71 || chr x >= 97 && chr x <= 103) then acc (++) x) [] xs
```

And when i try to load it on ghci it says i have a parse error in the last parenthesys so can you help me? What is wrong here?

Comment: You forgot the `else` case.

Comment: But it looks like you want to use a `filter` here.

Comment: I know it is easier to use filter but i want to use fold if it is possible

Comment: I didn't forget the else because in this case is not necessary at least I think so

Comment: in Haskell an `if` has *always* a `then` and `else` since you do not specify *actions* but functions. It also looks like you here ignore the `acc`, as a result, this will return a *function*, not a string.

Comment: So how do i do this without the if and with the foldl?

Comment: I did it with filter which has worked but i wanted to try it with foldl or foldr

Comment: @RuiFernando Consider doing it *with* the `if`. What would happen in the `else` branch? Think about what you have in the `then` branch and think about how it would be different in the `else` case. Also, don't put parentheses around an operator that you are using infix: `acc (++) x` is not the same as `acc ++ x`. You will want the second one since that is the one that uses `++` as an infix operator (there is a type error there as well, but I think that will put you on the right track for that part).

Comment: `Char` has an `Ord` instance; you can write `x >= 'A' && x <= 'G' || x >= 'a' && x <=  'g'`. Even simpler, just use ``toLower x `elem` ['a'..'g']`` (as `Char` also has an `Enum` instance).

Comment: I realy don't get it what to put in the else case because i don't see another case. Like if the char isn't between that values it will just ignore it

Comment: @RuiFernando Well, can you describe what you are doing in the `then` case (in terms of `acc` and `x`)? What does the function you have in the `foldl` do when it is in the `then` case?

Comment: Nevermind this is my new attempt     foldl (\acc x -> if toLower x `elem` ['a'..'g'] then acc ++ x else acc) [] xs

Comment: I want to put the x always in the end of the string

Comment: @RuiFernando You've almost got it! Think about the type of `(++)`. Willem Van Onsem's suggestion would give the correct order if you were using `foldr` (instead of `foldl`).

Comment: So if i put foldr it is done? Not really understanding the fold

Comment: @RuiFernando I would suggest continuing with `foldl` right now since you are so close, and then figure out `foldr` afterwards. Like I said: the remaining error you have is due to how you are using `++`. Specifically, the type is wrong. You should look at the type of `++` and compare it to the types of the two things you are giving it. Also, [these diagrams](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/introtohaskell2011-04-13-170607095410/95/introduction-to-haskell-20110413-83-638.jpg?cb=1496829637) I find useful in understanding the folds (the ones at the bottom of the slide).

Comment: So i made this    foldl (\acc x -> if toLower x `elem` ['a'..'g'] then (x:acc) else acc) [] xs with the string "ag12" and it gave me the ouput "ga" but i want it to give me "ag". How do i do it?

Comment: Nevermind just used `reverse`

Comment: Well, the key to fixing the original `foldl` code is understanding why `acc ++ x` gives a type error. Consider the type of `x` and compare to the type `(++)` expects.

Comment: Yeah now i got it right. Thank you all guys

Answer (score 0):

You are finding all occurrecne of letters A to G in a string in case in sensitive manner. As said in comments you are missing the else case. The else case should simply be returning the acc variable.

But still there are mistakes in your program. The function chr takes a number and returns ascii character. What you need is ord, which takes char and returns ascii value.

So the version of your program will be

```
ola xs = foldl (\acc x -> if (ord x >= 65 && ord x <= 71 || ord x >= 97 && ord x <= 103) then acc ++ [x] else acc) [] xs
```

Char data type is already of the Ord class, so you can compare them. No need for using ord. With this you can write above as

```
ola xs = foldl (\acc x -> if (x >= 'A' && x <= 'G' || x >= 'a' && x <= 'g') then acc ++ [x] else acc) [] xs
```

There is special function in list known as filter which takes from a list only the needed elements. Using filter the above program will be.

```
ola xs = filter (\x -> x >= 'A' && x <= 'G' || x >= 'a' && x <= 'g') xs
```

now the argument can simply be removed and it can be simply written as

```
ola = filter (\x -> x >= 'A' && x <= 'G' || x >= 'a' && x <= 'g')
```

*Bonus :-* 
But now what if you have some random character you want to check. You can first create a string for the characters you want to filter. For the above example this will suffice.

```
strList=['A'..'G','a'..'g'];
```

Now filter using elem. elem checks if a given element is present in string.

```
ola xs = filter (\x -> elem x strList) xs
```

*Bonus 2:-* 
What if you want to remove the arguments xs. For that first you need to first flip the arguments of the elem, so that the list will be first.

```
ola = filter ((flip elem) strList)
```